# Trouble reading width and height of a div element using clientWidth and offsetWidth

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I want to resize a canvas element dynamically. My page is split up in two parts where the left side has  some settings and the right side has a canvas element. As the page may be resized the canvas element should be resized along with it. 
So far I am trying to achieve this with CSS grid and an eventlistener which resizes the canvas element everytime the window is resized.

Now to the actual problem: When I set the canvas width and height to the CanvasContainer's width and height (in the function run by the eventlistener), the CanvasContainer div does not resize correctly. In fact when I make the window's width smaller the div's width increases. If i leave those two lines the CanvasContainer div resizes as expected.

HTML:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Control">
        <input id="StateCodeText" type="text" placeholder="State code">
        <br>
        <input id="StateOutputText" type="text" placeholder="State output">
        <br>
       <button id="NewStateButton">New state</button> 
    </div>

    <div class="CanvasContainer">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
let CanvasContainer = document.querySelector(".CanvasContainer");
Resize();

window.addEventListener("resize", Resize);

function Resize() {
   canvas.width = CanvasContainer.clientWidth;
   canvas.height = CanvasContainer.clientHeight; 
}
```

CSS:

```
.Container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr;
    height: 100%;
}

.CanvasContainer {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 13);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to define `canvas` in your js? Maybe give an id to it

`<canvas id=canvas'></canvas>` and then define

`const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')`

But maybe this approach isn't the best anyway. The css grid will make sure to resize all the elements by itself. So far there also doesn't seem to be the need for the canvas container. So how about instead

```
<div class="Container">
   <div class="Control">
      ...   
   </div>
   <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

and some css

```
.Container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr;
    height: 100%;
}

#canvas {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 13);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you do need the current size of the canvas at some point you could always access it by

`const width = document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect().width`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did not include the code where I define canvas, but I define the canvas using querySelector. 
The reason for resizing the canvas through JS is because you have to set the canvas' size through it's designated 'width' and 'height' attributes. If I do it using CSS anything drawn on canvas will be strechted (a bit like when images get streched).